# Nodejs socket.io through TOR

Tags: node.js

To bypass proxy at school I use TOR.
I got a server at home who runs a hidden service which is a simple socket.io server.

But I got a problem, I don't know how to proxy socket.io-client through TOR.
Tor is listening on port 9150 and the proxy type is Socks5.

I don't know if I am clear enough.

So if someone can help me, it would be very very nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make HTTP requests, you don't need to do anything differently for Socket.IO.

Socket.IO uses many transports, such as Web Sockets, Flash, and long-polling JSON.  Your browser should be able to use a Socks5 proxy for any of these.  At a minimum, long-polling JSON should always work.